# Exponent or power calculation in saxon9HE

Tags: xslt-2.0

Please suggest how to do math functions like **power** in XSLT2 with Saxon 9HE.

Getting following error:
`Cannot find a matching 2-argument function named {http://exslt.org/math}power()`

**XML:**

```
<root><num>12.3</num></root>
```

**XSLT 2.0:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
xmlns:math="http://exslt.org/math"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl math">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!--1/(1+e^(-t))--><!-- this is required formula -->

<xsl:template match="num">
    <xsl:variable name="varE"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="varT"><xsl:text>0.718</xsl:text></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="varPower">
     <xsl:value-of select="1 div (1 + math:power(number($varE), number(-$varT)))"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:value-of select="$varPower"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are XPath standardized `math` functions like `math:pow` e.g. `math:pow(2, 4)` in the namespace https://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math e.g with the namespace declaration `xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"` available in all editions of Saxon (at least with 9.8 but I think it also works with earlier version like 9.7 and 9.6 (documentation http://saxonica.com/html/documentation9.6/functions/math/pow.html says since 9.6 in all editions).